# How to scrape/attain a url from tfs source control and append it to a markdown file?

Tags: tfs

I'm in the process of setting up a prototype for documentation generation using source controlled files on tfs via docfx.

I'd like to be able to create a link on each article such that upon clicking it, it directs me to the file on tfs.

For example, if I have a file called index.md and the url for it is

http://tfs:8080/tfs/{collection}/{directory}/{restofthepath}Findex.md&_a=contents

I'd like to be able to somehow append that url as a link in index.md. Is there a way to do this?

In essence I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically copy/paste the tfs url path for every article/md file to the file itself so that I can later generate an edit link.

At the moment, I would need to go through every file and copy paste the tfs url into an href.

A little clarification:

- index.md stored in tfs under some link, lets call it tfs:8080:blabla
- I want to store that link in index.md somehow (naturally, I can simply copy paste tfs:8080:blabla into index.md and now index.md has a link pointing to where it's sourced) - any way to make an automated process for this?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: There's no code in particular. I am just asking if such a process is possible and if so, how?

Comment: Are you aware that TFS already has a wiki feature that does exactly what you're describing?

Comment: I am not aware, could you please direct me to this information? Thank you.

edit: I realize tfs has a wiki feature - but I am using docfx to generate documentation rather than using tfs's wiki